# hdfs configuration

Tags: hdfs

I am a newbie. Trying to setup a hdfs system to serve my data (I don't plan to use mapreduce) at my lab.

So far I have read, cluster setup in  but I am still confused.
Several questions:

- Do I need to have a secondary namenode?
- There are 2 files, masters and
  slaves. Do I really need these 2
  files eventhough I just want hdfs? If
  I need them, what should go in there?
  I assume my namenode in masters and
  datanodes as slaves? [Do I need slaves nodes](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/cluster_setup.html#Slaves)
- What configuration files are needed
  for namenode, secondary namenode,
  datanode and client? (I assume
  core-site.xml is needed for all 4)? In addition, can someone suggest a good
  configuration model? sample
  configuration for namenode, secondary
  namenode, datanode, and the client would be very helpful.

I am getting confused because it seems most of the documentation assumes I want to use map-reduce which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 1st 2 questions 
1. No you do not need secondary namenode if you dont care if the the namenode crashes
2. You need slave files to start the datanode daemons from the namenode using hadoop bash command start-dfs.sh. You do not need masters file if you do not want to use secondard namenode

For your 3rd question
There is step by step documentation on how to install a small hadoop cluster at
http://www.hadoop-blog.com/2010/11/how-to-quickly-install-hadoop-020-in.html

Please go thru it, you can skip the steps that talk about JobTracker and Tasktrackers and that should be enough to start your HDFS.

Comment: Invalid link. See http://hadoop-blog.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-quickly-install-hadoop-020-in.html